# Grok parse error while trying to parse kafka logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm getting a logstash grok parse failure that I can't seem to figure out...

The input looks like this:

```
"@timestamp" => 2017-03-30T13:03:41.899Z,
 "tst_field" => "test123avc",
  "@version" => "1",
   "message" => "[group-consumer-master,message-qa,8]::[OffsetMetadata[2,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1490878047368,ExpirationTime 1490964447368]",
      "tags" => [
    [0] "_grokparsefailure"
]
```

and I've tried the filter part like this:

```
filter{
        grok {
                match => {"meessage" => [
                                "\[%{DATA:kafka_consumer_group},%{DATA:kafka_topic},%{NUMBER:kafka_topic_parition}\]::\[OffsetMetadata\[%{NUMBER:kafka_offset_group},%{DATA:message_metadata}\],CommitTime %{NUMBER:commit_time},ExpirationTime %{NUMBER:expiration_time}\]"
                                ]
                         }
        }
}
```

but I keep getting a grok parse error. I've tried this in http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and it seems to work...

here is the error I get in the log file

```
Error parsing json {:source=>"message", :raw=>"[group-consumer-master,message-qa,8]::[OffsetMetadata[2,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1490878047368,ExpirationTime 1490964447368]", :exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unrecognized token 'group': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

----EDIT-------

here is the full config:

```
input {
        kafka {
                topics => ["kafka-offsets"]
                bootstrap_servers => "kafka1.domain.com:9092"
                group_id => "logstash_offsets_parser3"
        }

}
filter{
        grok {
                match => {"meessage" => "\[%{DATA:kafka_consumer_group},%{DATA:kafka_topic},%{NUMBER:kafka_topic_parition}\]\:\:\[OffsetMetadata\[%{NUMBER:kafka_offset_group},%{DATA:message_metadata}\],CommitTime\ %{NUMBER:commit_time},ExpirationTime\ %{NUMBER:expiration_time}\]"
                         }
        }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }
}
```

--EDIT-----

I spelled message wrong...I spelled in `meessage`....changed it to `message` and now its working....

Comment: It's always those little bitty typos.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says this:

> Error parsing json {:source=>"message" ...

That strongly suggests that somewhere in your filtering pipeline, you have a block that looks like this.

```
json {
  source => "message"
}
```

The `message` field you quoted at the top is not JSON formatted. I suggest you review the conditionals surrounding your `json {}` block, wherever it is, and make sure that this particular event never hits it.

The grokparsefailure message can be generated by any grok block you have. Check the conditionals around others as well, to ensure this event doesn't hit those inappropriately. If you want to make sure that *this* grok-block is the one that's failing parsing, I suggest setting `tag_on_failure` to something unique to that block, to be sure this is the one generating it.

Comment: I don't quite understand why would I need the json block (`json {
  source => "message"
}`)though when the `message` is just a string? I've tried to include that json block before the grok filter but it still doesn't work...

Comment: @user2061886 My point is that the `json {}` block is *unneeded here*, and is being applied anyway somehow. Or is an artifact of an earlier test-run where it was put before the grok filter.

Comment: Oh ok...I don't know why thats happening though...I made edit to show the full config file as well and I don't specify a json block anywhere in there...